# Delphi and Android: OrientationSensor doesn't have Tilt information

Tags: android, delphi, android-sensors

In a multi-device application developed with Delphi 10.2, I just created an empty form and drop in a `TOrientationSensor`.

`TOrientationSensor` does have tilt properties:

```
OrientationSensor1.Sensor.TiltX 
OrientationSensor1.Sensor.TiltY
OrientationSensor1.Sensor.TiltZ
```

But when queried, they returned a double with NAN value.

In order to understand what was going on, I dropped a button and a Memo, and I managed to display the content of `OrientationSensor1.Sensor.AvailableProperties`. The code is shown below.

What I got was only:

```
HeadingX
HeadingY
HEadingZ
```

So TiltX/Y/Z are not available. 
How can it be? Maybe I've to enable something at the device level?

**I tested it on a moto g6 plus; Android version is 8.0.0.**

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    properties: TCustomOrientationSensor.TProperties;
    prop: TCustomOrientationSensor.TProperty;
begin

OrientationSensor1.Active := true;

properties := OrientationSensor1.Sensor.AvailableProperties;

for prop in properties do begin
   Memo1.Lines.Add(TRttiEnumerationType.GetName(prop));
end;

end;
```

Comment: The OrientationSensor is totally broken on Android in Delphi 10.2.3; perhaps earlier. I don't think a report has been logged for it on https://quality.embarcadero.com

Comment: I should qualify that: totally broken on at least 2 devices I have, both with Android 8.1